# List item not showing correct text

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have two `ListView`s lets call them 1 and 2.  I add items to `ListView 1` and then after a certain amount of time, I move the item to `ListView 2`.

The problem I'm having is that sometimes (I haven't worked out the pattern yet) the text shown in `ListView 1` is wrong - it shows the previously created item's text.  But when I move it to `ListView 2` it shows the correct text.

I understand views are recycled so the list item could be using the old view.  I don't think it is doing this as it shows the correct info in the other list.

It could be that it is taking too long to set the text as there is a lot of it in the `getView()` method, so it uses the old values while it updates in the background. I don't know if this is possible, but even when I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` the wrong info is still being shown.

Here is my code:

`ListView 1`.

This is the adapter for the List:

```
  public class PendingAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 

            private List<Map<String, Object>> mPendingItemList;

            public PendingAdapter() {
                mPendingItemList = DataModel.getInstance().getPendingItemList();
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mPendingItemList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return mPendingItemList.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                if (null == convertView) {

                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                            R.layout.pending_item, null);

                }


                TextView tv_title = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.pi_tv_title);
                TextView tv_content = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.pi_tv_content);
                TextView tv_counter = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.pi_tv_counter);
                TextView tv_ongoing = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.pi_tv_ongoing);
                TextView tv_type = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.pi_tv_type);
                TextView tv_date = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.pi_tv_date);

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> itemDataHashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) getItem(position);

                tv_title.setText(itemDataHashMap.get("planet"));
                tv_content.setText(itemDataHashMap.get("content"));
                tv_counter.setText(itemDataHashMap.get("counter"));
                tv_type.setText(itemDataHashMap.get("type"));
                tv_ongoing.setText(itemDataHashMap.get("ongoing"));
                tv_date.setText(itemDataHashMap.get("date"));

                return convertView;
            }
        }
```

I am not sure which other pieces of code would be helpful (maybe the `mPendingItemList`) - but if more would help please say :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this one
public class PendingAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 

        private List<Map<String, Object>> mPendingItemList;

        public PendingAdapter() {
            mPendingItemList = DataModel.getInstance().getPendingItemList();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mPendingItemList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mPendingItemList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (null == convertView) {

                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                        R.layout.pending_item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.tv_title = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.pi_tv_title);
                holder.tv_content = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.pi_tv_content);
                holder.tv_counter = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.pi_tv_counter);
                holder.tv_ongoing = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.pi_tv_ongoing);
                holder.tv_type = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.pi_tv_type);
                holder.tv_date = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.pi_tv_date);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> itemDataHashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) getItem(position);

            holder.tv_title.setText(itemDataHashMap.get("planet"));
            holder.tv_content.setText(itemDataHashMap.get("content"));
            holder.tv_counter.setText(itemDataHashMap.get("counter"));
            holder. tv_type.setText(itemDataHashMap.get("type"));
            holder.tv_ongoing.setText(itemDataHashMap.get("ongoing"));
            holder.tv_date.setText(itemDataHashMap.get("date"));

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView tv_title;
            TextView tv_content;
            TextView tv_counter;
            TextView tv_ongoing;
            TextView tv_type;
            TextView tv_date;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - would you be able to explain why this works please?